# saving a birthday as date type on database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datepicker

Hi i want to save borthday using date  picker on asp.net. on my db data type is Date. I have tried but data is not saving . please advice

product.aspx

```
 protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (new bizObj().AddBiz(new BizEnt(Convert.ToInt32(txtBizId.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtUserId.Text), txtBizName.Text, txtBizAddress.Text, calcbizBorn.SelectedDate, Convert.ToInt32(txtBizBooks.Text))))
        {
            Response.Write("Successs"); 
            fillGird();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Error");
        }
    }




public Boolean AddBiz(BizEnt BizObj)
    {
        string qua = "exec addBiz'" + BizObj.Biz_Id + "','"
            + BizObj.User_Id + "','" + BizObj.Biz_Name + ","
              + BizObj.Biz_Address + "','" + BizObj.Biz_Born + "'"
                + BizObj.Bizr_Books + "'.'";

        return (new DataAccessLayer().executeNonQuaries(qua));
    }




public DateTime Biz_Born
    {
        get { return _BizBorn; }
        set { _BizBorn = value; }
    }
```

Comment: is there showing any error ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi : not shwing errors but it giong to Else loop and showing "error"  message

Comment: Can you post that error message here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your qua string is wrong check that by executing on sql and change

```
'" + BizObj.Biz_Born + "'
```

to

```
" + BizObj.Biz_Born + "
```